# Date data type issue in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, powerbi

In Excel sheet I havea column data where some set of records are in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and some are in 'mm-dd-yyyy'. But I need all records in one format with data type as "DATE". How could I achieve?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rudK0.png) [image]

I have tried by changing data type into 'date' format but while doing transformations in power bi errors occured because there data format loaded as text format. it is not allowing any date operations.

Comment: Is it an Excel question? Or a Power Query (Extract, Transform &Load) one? Because Excel does it automatically... (assuming your dates are expected to be in MDY order).

Comment: Even though the Date data is text format in Excel, the data is converted to one date format automatically when imported into Power BI.

Comment: The usual cause is that the original dates are in DMY order, but your windows regional settings are MDY. The fix is to go back to the original source, and, at the time of import into Excel or Power Query, you must inform the application of the date order in the data source. Often the source is a CSV or Text file. Can you access that original file?

Comment: In Excel also while I'm trying to split into columns only 'mm-dd-yyyy' format records are splitted but records with 'mm/dd/yyyy' format are not splitted into columns. I need to convert them into single format either mm-dd-yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.  @AntoineL

Comment: There are mixed records in excel you can see in my attachment. In power query only records with m/d/y format are working remaining(m-d-y) are showing errors @Kevin

Comment: @sandeep - Yes, in Excel the m-d-y format is text type and m/d/y format is date type. But when I try the transformation, they are converted to one date format in Power BI correctly. Can you attach a screenshot of your power bi errors on your post?

Comment: @Kevin- I have added the image of power query. where 'birthdate' in text format and 'parse' is the transformed column of date type.

Comment: @sandeep - I understand you. You need to change the Power BI option. I attached a screenshot on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

- right click on the header of the column
- select "replace values"
- enter "-" and "/" (without quotes) in 'value to find' and 'replace with'
- change the data type to "date"

Answer (score -1):

If you can guarantee that the format is either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy` you can transform both your columns at the same time using the optional `Culture` setting you can specify for `Date.FromText` in Power Query.

Here is an example:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [birthdate="8/26/1961", acct_open_date="09-10-1991"],
        [birthdate="03-07-1915", acct_open_date="8/21/1992"]
    }),
    #"Parsed Date" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,
        {
            {"birthdate", each Date.FromText(_,"en-US"), type date},
            {"acct_open_date", each Date.FromText(_,"en-US"), type date}
        })
in
    #"Parsed Date"
```

To implement, you will have to use the Advanced Editor or the Formula Bar. Here is a step-by-step:

1. Load your table
2. Select e.g. `birthdate` and click `Transform > Date > Parse`.
3. In your formula bar, replace the entire code with this:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(Source,
        {
            {"birthdate", each Date.FromText(_,"en-US"), type date},
            {"acct_open_date", each Date.FromText(_,"en-US"), type date}
        })
```

4. You should have the dates readily transformed now:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the Power BI options. `Power BI -> File -> Options and settings -> Options`
Try to change the Regional Settings to English (United States).

[image]

Comment: This answer may work but changing the locale of Power BI for one table import seems like a bad solution since this affects all imports.

Comment: No problem. English (United States), it is a standard setting. If not, all fields related to the issue need to be parsed. It is too much hassle.

Comment: It is a standard setting for developers that live in the US. Having the locale set to US would be at my detriment living in EU, since that would cause all my other dates to fail when parsed. I am sure you understand.

Comment: @Kevin - At this moment, for this data I have  it is working as expected after changing regional settings to English-US. Tank you Kevin.

Comment: Please accept the above answer if it solves your problem.